# npm ERR code EPERM syscall unlink while executing npm install

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

Got the following error while executing `npm install`

node version 12.16.2
Running cmd as administrator

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path D:\Projects\BTP\Medical-Project\client\node_modules\.staging\npm-9e4fc1a9\man\man5\package-locks.5
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Projects\BTP\Medical-Project\client\node_modules\.staging\npm-9e4fc1a9\man\man5\package-locks.5'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Projects\BTP\Medical-Project\client\node_modules\.staging\npm-9e4fc1a9\man\man5\package-locks.5'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Projects\BTP\Medical-Project\client\node_modules\.staging\npm-9e4fc1a9\man\man5\package-locks.5'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'D:\\Projects\\BTP\\Medical-Project\\client\\node_modules\\.staging\\npm-9e4fc1a9\\man\\man5\\package-locks.5'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\\Projects\\BTP\\Medical-Project\\client\\node_modules\\.staging\\npm-9e4fc1a9\\man\\man5\\package-locks.5'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Projects\\BTP\\Medical-Project\\client\\node_modules\\.staging\\npm-9e4fc1a9\\man\\man5\\package-locks.5',
npm ERR!   parent: 'client'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-01T18_15_01_424Z-debug.log
```

I tried :

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. deleted node_modules and installed again
3. disabled antivirus
4. Restarting laptop :)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by

1. Closing any open prompts and editors eg. VSCode.
2. Opening the terminal or CMD as admin and running `npm-install` again.

I think the IDE is 'locking a file'.